# Lateral Slip of car

Tags: car, vehicle, physics

I have been following this Gaming Institute tutorial and tried to make that car physics system in Blender Game Engine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdjUS85yVuI&list=PLMT7gzj_bnSu7aENsf7_4tuvWadOzu4hY&index=3

However, once I got to 1:47:30 where he starts to talk about lateral slip speed I got confused(propably because I don't know how Unity's scripting works). So it is told there that:
`lateral slip speed is equal to car speed dotted by wheel sideways transform`. However, I don't know how to correctly do it. I mean it that I don't know if I need to take in local(multiplied by worldTransform matrix in terms of how game engines works) or global speed of car. And I also don't know if to use vector `(1, 0, 0)` or a global vector(in BGE it's `wheel.getAxisVect((1, 0, 0))` as second input.
Thanks for answers;)